# Laravel 4.2 One to One relationship return NULL

Tags: sql, laravel, eloquent, relationship

I would like to implementations  this query with Laravel one to one relationship.

```
SELECT `path_filepath` from path where `path_id` = (SELECT `path_id` from file where file_id = 1)
```

I'd like to `Filedb::find(1)->path()->path_filepath`. but `path()` always return NULL.

```
[database]

table: file
file_id
file_name
path_id

table: path
path_id
path_filepath
```

Model

```
class Filedb extends Eloquent {
        public $timestamps = false; 
        protected $table = 'file';
        protected $primaryKey = 'file_id';
        protected $connection = 'dl_database';

        public function path(){
            return $this->hasOne('Filepath','path_id','path_id');
        }
}


class Filepath extends Eloquent {
        public $timestamps = false; 
        protected $table = 'path';
        protected $primaryKey = 'path_id';
        protected $connection = 'dl_database';   

        public function filedb()
        {
            return $this->belongsTo('Filedb', 'path_id');
        }
}
```

My Controller

```
var_dump(Filedb::find(1)->path());
echo '<br>';
$queries = DB::connection('dl_database')->getQueryLog();
$last_query = end($queries);
var_dump($queries);
```

Outout

```
NULL 
array(1) { [0]=> array(3) { ["query"]=> string(61) "select * from `file` where `file`.`file_id` = ? limit 1" ["bindings"]=> array(1) { [0]=> int(1) } ["time"]=> float(0.85) } }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's `belongsTo` not hasOne

```
public function path(){
    return $this->belongsTo('Filepath','path_id','path_id');
}
```

and this is `hasOne`

```
public function filedb()
{
    return $this->hasOne('Filedb', 'path_id', 'path_id');
}
```

Comment: Thanks working, but you path function missing return.

Comment: @dragon1993 well, yeah, just like yours. I copy-pasted it from your code ;)